# Convert weekly data into daily data with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I will try to be as clear as possible in this question. Let's say I have a dataframe formed as:

```
Date          Quantity
05/05/2017    34
12/05/2017    24
19/05/2017    45
26/05/2017    23
2/06/2017     56
9/06/2017     32
```

I would like to convert this dataframe having weekly data (as you see) into one having daily data. However, there will be some "holes" in my dataframe (ex. week-end days). I already have stored the daily dates into another variable.
I would like to obtain something like this:

```
Date          Quantity
05/05/2017    34
08/05/2017    34
09/05/2017    34
...           ...
2/06/2017     56
5/06/2017     56
6/06/2017     56
...           ...
```

My idea is to have a loop that says "whenever the date is prior to the date in the weekly dataframe (ex. 19/05/2017) but higher than the previous date (so 12/05/2017), I want to append to the column "Quantity" in the daily dataframe the correct number (in this case 45).

However, I do not know how to do this in Python. Should I convert the dates into numbers and then back to dates? Does anyone have any faster way to do this? Thank you very much

Comment: you're not actually using the daily dates for anything, so what's the point? why convert that?

Comment: or, in a more generic sense, you get no more data by converting weekly to daily. your logic should be able to check on a week-by-week basis vs a day-by-day basis

Comment: I was just trying to keep my code simple. I need the data to be in such a way in order to append this column of data to a huge dataframe containing daily data. The problem is, for this column I only have weekly data

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option using [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [*business day frequency*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) (B) and forward fill:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')    
df.set_index('Date').resample('B').ffill().reset_index()

#         Date  Quantity
#0  2017-05-05      34
#1  2017-05-08      34
#2  2017-05-09      34
#...
#20 2017-06-02      56
#21 2017-06-05      56
#22 2017-06-06      56
#...
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the missing value part of the question. One could, though, merge this output with a single-column dataframe of the desired dates, `resampled_df.merge(days, how='right')`, to get the target output.

Comment: @EFT You're right. I missed that part. A `resample` with busingness day frequency should resolve the issue.

Comment: To use this normally with a days frequency use `resample('D')`

Answer (score 2):

If we say that your daily data is in a variable named `days` and `Date` is your index, then

```
>>>df.reindex(days).fillna(method='ffill')
```

should return  what you want.

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for, thank you very much