# How to transform many_days to daily in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following `dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
    dt = pd.DataFrame({'start_date': ['2019-05-20', '2019-05-21', '2019-05-21'],
                       'end_date': ['2019-05-23', '2019-05-24', '2019-05-22'],
                       'reg': ['A', 'B','A'],
                       'measure': [100, 200,1000]})
```

I would to create a new column, called 'date', which will have values from `start_date` until `end_date` and also have a new column `measure_daily` which will be the `measure` spread equally among these dates.

So basically, I would like to expand the `dt` in terms of rows

So I would like the final df to look like:

```
   dt_f = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-05-20','2019-05-21','2019-05-22','2019-05-23','2019-05-21','2019-05-22','2019-05-23','2019-05-24', '2019-05-21','2019-05-22'],
                            'reg':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A'],
                             'measure_daily':[25,25,25,25,50,50,50,50,500,500]})
```

Is there an efficient way to do this in python ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572818/convert-weekly-data-into-daily-data-with-python

Comment: So you want to expand the dataframe in terms of rows?

Comment: @Erfan yes, exactly

Comment: @Xcodebeginner that question has two major differences: it doesnt take into account a date range, and it also doesnt spread the measure equally

Comment: But how do you see the fact that your start and enddate are overlapping for the different `reg`?

Comment: @Erfan then for some rows, the new column `date` would have the same date value, but the `measure` would be different, and also the `reg` would be different

Comment: @Erfan I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now !

Comment: why is there just 4 rows for A, the date range between start and end is 11 days..?

Comment: @anky_91 I edited the initial `dt` in order to create a "reproducible end result". Both A & B now have 4 days each

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

*just give me the solution:*

```
dt = dt.assign(key=dt.index)
melt = dt.melt(id_vars = ['reg', 'measure', 'key'], value_name='date').drop('variable', axis=1)

melt = pd.concat(
    [d.set_index('date').resample('d').first().ffill() for _, d in melt.groupby(['reg', 'key'], sort=False)]
).reset_index()

melt.assign(measure = melt['measure'].div(melt.groupby(['reg', 'key'], sort=False)['reg'].transform('size'))).drop('key', axis=1)
```

---

#### Breakdown:

First we [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) your `start` and `end date` to the same column:

```
dt = dt.assign(key=dt.index)
melt = dt.melt(id_vars = ['reg', 'measure', 'key'], value_name='date').drop('variable', axis=1)

  reg  measure  key       date
0   A      100    0 2019-05-20
1   B      200    1 2019-05-21
2   A     1000    2 2019-05-21
3   A      100    0 2019-05-23
4   B      200    1 2019-05-24
5   A     1000    2 2019-05-22
```

Then we [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) on daily basis while applying `groupby` to keep the different `reg` in their own group.

```
melt = pd.concat(
    [d.set_index('date').resample('d').first().ffill() for _, d in melt.groupby(['reg', 'key'], sort=False)]
).reset_index()

        date reg  measure  key
0 2019-05-20   A    100.0  0.0
1 2019-05-21   A    100.0  0.0
2 2019-05-22   A    100.0  0.0
3 2019-05-23   A    100.0  0.0
4 2019-05-21   B    200.0  1.0
5 2019-05-22   B    200.0  1.0
6 2019-05-23   B    200.0  1.0
7 2019-05-24   B    200.0  1.0
8 2019-05-21   A   1000.0  2.0
9 2019-05-22   A   1000.0  2.0
```

Finally we spread out the `measure` column over the `size` of each group with [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
melt.assign(measure = melt['measure'].div(melt.groupby(['reg', 'key'], sort=False)['reg'].transform('size'))).drop('key', axis=1)

        date reg  measure
0 2019-05-20   A     25.0
1 2019-05-21   A     25.0
2 2019-05-22   A     25.0
3 2019-05-23   A     25.0
4 2019-05-21   B     50.0
5 2019-05-22   B     50.0
6 2019-05-23   B     50.0
7 2019-05-24   B     50.0
8 2019-05-21   A    500.0
9 2019-05-22   A    500.0
```

Comment: do you think, there is a way to expand this solution, in case you had an overlap in dates but within the same region ?

Comment: How would overlapping dates look like within the same region? You mean that somewhere further on the dataset `region A` will show again with overlapping dates? @quant

Comment: yes, exactly. @killswitch solution i think does that

Comment: Last question, does it happen that a new `reg` down the dataframe has the same `measure` value as the same reg but then further up the dataframe? @quant

Comment: Last edit, this should give correct output and should run fast on big data frame